# how to see the robot path

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

What should I do to see the path done by the robot during the simulation in gazebo non in rviz?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/912/how-to-see-the-robot-path/) by [camilla](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/150/camilla/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-01-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If you can use ROS/rviz (and do not have to do it in gazebo), [this Q/A on ROS Answers](http://answers.ros.org/question/28069/how-to-visualize-a-frame-pose-as-a-path/) might provide a solution for you.

There's also [ticket on Bitbucket on rendering via messages](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/382/render-via-message). I'm not aware of any other possibilities to do what you require, but I hope someone else will chime in in case I missed them.

/edit: In reaction to your comment: If your want to compare data, it might make sense to also visualize the ground truth trajectory coming from gazebo in rviz. You could do this by using the [Gazebo ROS API](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/Gazebo_ROS_API) to retrieve the ground truth model state. Another option would be to add a gazebo_ros_p3d plugin similar to how it's done [here](http://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_gazebo/urdf/quadrotor_sensors.urdf.xacro) to your robot to output ground truth data to a topic.
Both method would enable visualization of the ground truth pose from gazebo in rviz. If you really want to render directly in gazebo, you will have to wait for [the issue on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/382/render-via-message) to be resolved. Luckily, Nate just marked it critical ;)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/9/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 473 on 2013-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [camilla](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/150/camilla/) on 2013-01-22**:
Thx, but I'm yet able to do it in rviz, i have the problem that what the robot does in rviz is different from what it does in gazebo so I want to do it in gazebo too for debbuging purposes.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/9/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-01-23**:
I edited my answer with some more info in response to your comment, see above.